# How to set properly "content-security-policy" for Cordova Ios/Windows Phone/Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, content-security-policy, taco

I am building an app for our company. We are having an iframe (don't ask why...) loading a responsive website. It is (should) be transparent for the user.

I added few js lines in order to manage offline pages.

It is running well on android simulator (cordova with Visual Studio) and android Device. However I am facing a `content-security-policy` that I suspect to be the source of this error:

> deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

From what I have read it could come from content security policy.

I got this error on run:

> Refused to load frame 'gap://ready' because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   https://www.mywebsite.fr
>   http://www.mywebsite.fr". Note that 'frame-src'
>   was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

What do you think of this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.mywebsite.fr http:///www.mywebsite.fr; child-src 'self' https:///www.mywebsite.fr http:///www.mywebsite.fr; script-src 'self' https:///www.mywebsite.fr http:///www.mywebsite.fr; 
         gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And my config.xml:

```
  <access origin="https:///www.mywebsite.fr" />
<access origin="http:///www.mywebsite.fr" />
```

Thanks for your time,

Stéf.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your content security policy and see if the error persists?

Comment: Yes: same error with or without it. (I edited my post)

Answer (score 1):

The CSP error gives you all of the details. You do not have a 'frame-src' directive specified so it is falling back to 'default-src' which does not whitelist the gap: protocol.

You have two choices:

1) Add `gap:` to your 'default-src'.

2) Add a 'frame-src' directive and add `gap:` to that.

If you go for 2, you may also want to add the 'child-src' directive for future compatibility with the same value as 'frame-src'.